# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on POST call to api

Tags: jquery, python

I know there are many other articles on this topic but unfortunately none of the solutions worked for me.

I am running linux red hat 7.2 with apache 2.4 (httpd). I am working on the server directly as localhost. The API is python based which i have little experience with - i downloaded the program from github [mozilla http observatory](https://github.com/mozilla/http-observatory).

I have tried different settings for several hours and have made no progress on this issue and now seeking further assistance.

The main page before I am on before POST is http://localhost

**Here is the js (ajax)**

A POST XHR call is made to: http://localhost:57001/api/v1/scan

```
function loadTLSObservatoryResults(rescan, initiateScanOnly) {
    'use strict';

    var rescan = typeof rescan !== 'undefined' ? rescan : false;
    var initiateScanOnly = typeof initiateScanOnly !== 'undefined' ? initiateScanOnly : false;

    /*var SCAN_URL = 'https://tls-observatory.services.mozilla.com/api/v1/scan';
    var RESULTS_URL = 'https://tls-observatory.services.mozilla.com/api/v1/results';
    var CERTIFICATE_URL = 'https://tls-observatory.services.mozilla.com/api/v1/certificate';*/
    var SCAN_URL = 'http://localhost:57001/api/v1/scan';
    var RESULTS_URL = 'http://localhost:57001/api/v1/results';
    var CERTIFICATE_URL = 'http://localhost:57001/api/v1/certificate';

    // if it's the first scan through, we need to do a post
    if (Observatory.state.third_party.tlsobservatory.scan_id === undefined || rescan) {
        // make a POST to initiate the scan
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                rescan: rescan,
                target: Observatory.hostname
            },
            initiateScanOnly: initiateScanOnly,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            error: function() { errorResults('Scanner unavailable', 'tlsobservatory') },
            success: function (data) {
                Observatory.state.third_party.tlsobservatory.scan_id = data.scan_id;

                if (this.initiateScanOnly) { return; }

                loadTLSObservatoryResults();  // retrieve the results
            },
            url: SCAN_URL
        });
```

**Here is my httpd.conf**

basically just included this line:
`LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so`

**Here is my .htaccess file:**

```
RewriteEngine On

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

I have restarted apache but i see the same warning in the developer console:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:57001/api/v1/scan. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).`

Comment: why `python` tag there?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, are you using a Javascript build environment like Ember or Angular on the client side? Because that will affect your hosted port, and could contribute to cross-origin related errors.

Another thing you could do is to modify your ajax slightly and create a helpder function as so:

```
    function myCallbackFunction(data){
            Observatory.state.third_party.tlsobservatory.scan_id = data.scan_id;

            if (this.initiateScanOnly) { return; }

            loadTLSObservatoryResults();  // retrieve the results

    }



     // make a POST to initiate the scan
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            rescan: rescan,
            target: Observatory.hostname
        },
        initiateScanOnly: initiateScanOnly,
        dataType: 'jsonp',

        method: 'POST',
        error: function() { errorResults('Scanner unavailable', 'tlsobservatory') },
        jsonpCallback: 'myCallbackFunction'
        url: SCAN_URL
    });
```

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: can you take a look at my post. I updated it to include the full function in case that means anything further to you

Comment: the cors warning went away but switching to jsonp seems to have changed it to a GET call somehow.. at least according to the developer console.

Comment: Yea jsonp payloads are GET. <strong> Try this </strong>


    $.ajax({
        data: {
            rescan: rescan,
            target: Observatory.hostname
        },
        initiateScanOnly: initiateScanOnly,
        dataType: false,
        processData, false,
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
       
        error: function() { errorResults('Scanner unavailable', 'tlsobservatory') },
        jsonpCallback: 'myCallbackFunction'
        url: SCAN_URL
    });

Comment: thanks Tom! unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Comment: When I had the same issue python a python tornado server, I just made sure the headers were written first into the response, and for origin i only had localhost. Also I changed my contentType to application/json. Hope it helps